# Evaluating trigonometric integral using contour integration

Tags: complex-analysis

$$
\int_0^{\pi}\left(\frac{m\left|\sin wt \right|}{1-m\left|\sin wt \right|}\right)^2d(wt)
$$

Does anyone know how to calculate this integral using complex integrals or any other method?. kindly help me.

Comment: What is the variable running from $0$ to $\pi $? If it is $wt $ what was the reason to use a two-letter code for it?

Answer (score 0):

Is $wt$ the variable, or is it $t$ with $w$ constant?

If $0 < wt < \pi$, $\sin(wt) > 0$ so you don't need the absolute values.
If you integrate over an interval where $\sin(wt)$ changes sign, you'll want to
split it up into cases where $\sin(wt) > 0$ and $< 0$.

The integrals of $(m \sin(wt)/(1 - m \sin(wt)))^2$ and $(m \sin(wt)/(1 + m \sin(wt)))^2$ can be done in closed form.  Try the substitution $u = \tan(wt/2)$.
But you'll want to ensure the denominator is not $0$ on the interval